# I have an error saying "Subquery returns more than 1 row "

Tags: sql, subquery

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT *,"
              +"(SELECT group_concat(gGenre) FROM spmovy_genre_table a,spmovy_genre b WHERE mID=mID "
              +"AND a.gID=b.gID group by mID) Genre "
              +"FROM spmovy_movie where mTitle "
              + "like ?";
```

I have a table fill with movie titles joined by a foreign key Genre table with gID, 1. table with movie title and mID then a second table with mgID, mID, gID to link with a third table with gID and gGenre

Answer (score 1):

Apart from general comments about your query (learn `join` syntax and use descriptive aliases), the problem with your query is the line:

```
mID = mID
```

in the not-quite-correlated subquery.

You are trying to get one set of genres.  But the query is returning one for each group.  And in a `select` within a `select`, you can't have multiple values.

You intend for this to correlate the subquery, but it is not.  You need table aliases for that.  Here is my guess as the right version:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT group_concat(gGenre)
        FROM spmovy_genre_table a join
             spmovy_genre b
             on a.gID=b.gID
        WHERE spmovy_movie.mID=b.mID
       ) Genre
FROM spmovy_movie
where mTitle like ?
```

The match could be to `a.mID` rather than to `b.mID`.

I also removed the `group by` clause, since that is no longer necessary.